# deactivate class with another event

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to make a individual dropdown  container like of that on the nopnav of the google, well everything runs ok, exept the fact that i would like to deactivate the activated class of the trigger event when i click on to hide the container!

---

Inserted the page where are the links where will be triggered to push up the container, and the second page is the content of the container, where i put in one script to hide the container and the second one to "tabfy" the menu with the jquery tools tabs.

---

**Here's the code:**

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $(".user-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(".user-link").hasClass("#buser-box")) {
            $(".user-link").removeClass("#buser-box");
        } else {
            $('#buser-box').show('fast');
            $(".user-link").addClass("active");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "conta-box/conta-home.html",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#buser-box").html(data);
                if (!$(this).hasClass("#buser-box")) {
                    $("#buser-box").removeClass("#buser-box");
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML of the Index:**

```
<div class="tabs-global">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="user-link" title="Conta"><a class="user-box"></a></li>
        <li class="loja-link" title="Loja"><a class="loja-box"></a></li>
        <li class="ava-link" title="Avaliação"><a class="ava-box"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="buser-box"></div>
<div id="loja-box"></div>
<div id="ava-box"></div>
```

**HTML of the container-content:**

```
<div class="topbar">
    <span class="box-close" onclick="box.close();"></span>
</div>
<div id="menu-box">
    <h2>
        <span class="icones-conta"></span><span class="texto">Conta</span></h2>
    <ul id="conta-tabs">
        <li class="current"><a href="box/conta-box/conf.html">Configuração</a></li>
        <li><a href="box/conta-box/conf-end.html">Localização</a></li>
        <li><a href="box/conta-box/compras.html">Compras</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="conta-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".box-close").click(function () {
        $("#buser-box").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be using IDs instead of classes... you can't remove a class name that starts with a `#`. Please share your HTML so we can better help you.

Comment: thank's guys, well now the html is there, the content container is a little messy but it's another history!

Comment: That's a start! But I don't see how you are trying to use the class which you have as `#buser-box`... where is the class added. And as I said before `#buser-box` is an ID and not a class, so what class should be added and removed?

Comment: the .active class on .user-link, well is activating when i click on, but i would like to deactivate when i click on the hide event of the #buser-box

Comment: Why do you have an ID symbol `#` in the `.hasClass()` and `.removeClass()`? Doesn't seem like that would work as it's seeing if it has a *class* and removing a *class*, but not an ID.

Comment: you're probably getting confused because you have defined styles for #buser-box in your css like; #buser-box { ..... }.  In your css try changing #buser-box { ... } to .buser-box { ... } and update all of your jquery hasClass("#buser-box") and removeClass("#buser-box") to hasClass("buser-box") and removeClass("buser-box").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use any Jquery property that refers to class, you then need to use a class.
>
> ```
> For example:
> ```

```
if ($(".user-link").hasClass("#buser-box")) {
    $(".user-link").removeClass("#buser-box");
}
```

> Should Be:

```
 if ($(".user-link").hasClass("buser-box")) {
        $(".user-link").removeClass("buser-box");
  }
```

> Also you could try a click function for showing and a click function
>   for hiding:

```
// hide your dropdown menu by default
    $('#myMenuContainer').addClass('closed').hide(); 


    $('.mylink').click(function(showMenu){
     //display your drop down menu
    if($('#myMenuContainer').hasClass('closed')) {
    $('#myMenuContainer').show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
    }
    });

    $('.mylink').click(function(showMenu){
    //hide your drop down menu
    if($('#myMenuContainer').hasClass('open')) {
    $('#myMenuContainer').removeClass('open').addClass('closed').hide();
    }
    });
```